# COLLADA transformations in SceneKit

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, scenekit

We try to make viewer for models in Xcode and use SceneKit to render model. If we add COLLADA (.dae) file to Xcode, it transforms the model using `scntool` to `c3d` format (found this on the Internet). But we want to load models in runtime (we download them from server to iOS device). How can we  transform `.dae` to this format not from Mac OS? Our server running Ubuntu, we can transform model and send it already converted to iOS devices.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run `scntool` manually but you'll need a machine running OS X to do that. The compressed format used by SceneKit on iOS is not documented and there is no other tool that you can use to make the conversion.

Comment: There's some detail on exactly how to do that in the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739248/scenekit-which-way-is-up